# React phone input 2 with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using PhoneInput along with react hook form, I want to enable save button only if phone number is valid

**Code:**

```
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitRequest)}>
      .....................other code..............
       <Controller
        as={
          <PhoneInput
            id="pNum"
            placeholder="Enter phone number"
            className={classes.phoneInput}
            inputRef={register({required: true})}
            isValid={(inputNumber, onlyCountries) => {
              return onlyCountries.some((country) => {
                return startsWith(inputNumber, country.dialCode) || startsWith(country.dialCode, inputNumber);
              });
            }}
          />
        }
        name="phoneNumber"
        control={control}
      />
     ........................other code...................
     <Button
        fullWidth
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        color={'primary'}
        className={classes.submitBtn}
        data-testid="customerFormButton"
        disabled={!formState.isValid}
      >
        Save
      </Button>
  </form>
```

Here I used `PhoneInput` as controller along with `isValid` for it. How can I disable Save button for invalid phone number input?

Answer (score 2):

How are you? I believe that your problem is because you are not configuring the rules for the controller.

You need to change your controller to something like this:

```
<Controller
        as={
          <PhoneInput
            id="pNum"
            placeholder="Enter phone number"
            className={classes.phoneInput}
            inputRef={register}
            isValid={(inputNumber, onlyCountries) => {
              return onlyCountries.some((country) => {
                return startsWith(inputNumber, country.dialCode) || startsWith(country.dialCode, inputNumber);
              });
            }}
          />
        }
        name="phoneNumber"
        control={control}
        rules= {{required: true}}
      />
```

Comment: Property 'inputRef' does not exist on type - PhoneInput - from react-phone-input-2

Answer (score 0):

ref cannot be currently used on this element. react-phone-input-2.

Until its supported, you can provide a hidden input field which updates its value when the phone updates its value and put the ref on that
Example:

```js
import React, { FC, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2';
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css';

interface Props {
  handleChange: (name: string, val: string) => void;
  defaultValue: string;
  name: string;
}

const MyComponent: FC<Props> = ({ defaultValue, name, handleChange }) => {
  const { register, setValue, watch } = useFormContext(); // Note: needs <FormProvider> in parent for this to be acessible

  const nameHidden = `${name}Hidden`;
  const handleChangePhone = useCallback(
    (val: string) => {
      setValue(nameHidden, val, { shouldValidate: true });
      handleChange(name, val);
    },
    [handleChange]
  );
  return (
    <>
      <PhoneInput value={defaultValue as string} country="gb" onChange={handleChangePhone} />
      <input
        type="hidden"
        name={nameHidden}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        ref={register({
          // validate stuff here...
        })}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method is working fine for me.

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    phoneNo: yup.string().required("phone number is required."),
});

const { register, control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    mode: 'onTouched',
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
});

<Controller
    name="phoneNo"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=''
    //defaultValue={`${contactDetails.dialCode}${contactDetails.phoneNo}`} // if you have pre filled value.
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <PhoneInput
            country={'us'}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
    )}
/>
{ errors.phoneNo && <p>{errors.phoneNo.message}</p> }
```